# Create a HTMLHeadingElement in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a `HTMLHeadingElement`. To do that I use:

```
const myHeading: HTMLHeadingElement = document.createElement("h3");
```

So this works perfectly. But when I try to create this element more dynamically, I fail doing so:

```
const level: number = 3;
const headingLevel: string = "h" + level;
const myHeading: HTMLHeadingElement = document.createElement(headingLevel);
```

So, it looks like essentially the same thing, but apparently it isn't. The error I get when hovering `myHeading` is:

> Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLHeadingElement'

In the first example, though, the method `createElement("h3")` right away returns the type `HTMLHeadingElement`.

Now, my first question is, how are these two commands different? And if not clear then, how can I get the same result within `myHeading` in the second example as shown in the first example?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So, the 3 is indeed a number value. I updated the post.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Apologies for the missing info. I added it to the post.

Comment: Great stuff! When quoting error messages, it's generally best to copy and paste them, and use blockquoting to make it clear that you're quoting (see my edit). Happy coding! (And interesting question, I learned something about TypeScript's DOM type library today!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My error message is in German, so I couldn't copy and paste. Glad I could contribute to enlarge the knowledge of a 636k user. And also thank you for better defining the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript has many overloads for `createElement()` in its `lib.dom.d.ts` file, so it knows that when `createElement()` is called with 'h3', that will return an HTMLHeadingElement:

```
createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(tagName: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K];
createElement(tagName: string): HTMLElement;
```

When it doesn't know the tag name at compile time, all it knows is that the method returns an HTMLElement. You know that, however, so you can tell TypeScript:

```
const myHeading = document.createElement(headingLevel) as HTMLHeadingElement;
```

Answer (score 2):

`headingLevel` is declared to have type `string`. That means it can be *any* string, including, say, `"canvas"`, which would *not* lead to `myHeading` being a `HTMLHeadingElement`.

You need to be more specific with your types.

```
const headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6"
```

Unfortunately, it appears TypeScript will not let you make these as follows

```
const level: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6

// TypeScript's types don't know how literals are concatenated 
const headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" = "h" + level
```

So you'd need to transform `level` into its corresponding tag name using a dictionary or array or similar.

```
const LEVEL_MAP: {1: "h1", 2: "h2", 3: "h3", 4: "h4", 5: "h5", 6: "h6"} = {
    1: "h1",
    2: "h2",
    3: "h3",
    4: "h4",
    5: "h5",
    6: "h6",
}
const headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" = LEVEL_MAP[level]
```

... It would be nice if TypeScript supported `"h" + 1` being of type `"h1"`.

Comment: How can you lock the type of `LEVEL_MAP` to `string`? The type of `HEADING_LEVEL[level]` is `any and `HEADING_LEVEL[level] as string` doesn't work. Is there a way to set the index signature?

Comment: Yes, you can add an explicit type for each property that I forgot to include. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert returned object to `HTMLHeadingElement`

`const myHeading: HTMLHeadingElement = document.createElement(headingLevel) as HTMLHeadingElement;`